# I got this error "Command 'openmc -p' returned non-zero exit status 255."

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I using openMC on macOS Catalina install via conda. As tutorial [here](https://docs.openmc.org/en/stable/quickinstall.html).
Furthermore I use Jupyter notebook for writing code.
Then I tried example >> post_procesing [here](https://docs.openmc.org/en/stable/examples/post-processing.html)
I have no issue until

```
ln[9]: plot = openmc.Plot.from_geometry(geometry)
       plot.pixels = (250, 250)
       plot.to_ipython_image()
```

I got this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-4c671a78cd00> in <module>
      1 plot = openmc.Plot.from_geometry(geometry)
      2 plot.pixels = (250, 250)
----> 3 plot.to_ipython_image()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/openmc-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/plots.py in to_ipython_image(self, openmc_exec, cwd, convert_exec)
    703 
    704         # Run OpenMC in geometry plotting mode
--> 705         openmc.plot_geometry(False, openmc_exec, cwd)
    706 
    707         # Convert to .png

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/openmc-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/executor.py in plot_geometry(output, openmc_exec, cwd)
     48 
     49     """
---> 50     _run([openmc_exec, '-p'], output, cwd)
     51 
     52 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/openmc-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openmc/executor.py in _run(args, output, cwd)
     26     # Raise an exception if return status is non-zero
     27     if p.returncode != 0:
---> 28         raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, ' '.join(args),
     29                                             ''.join(lines))
     30 

CalledProcessError: Command 'openmc -p' returned non-zero exit status 255.
```

***So I try to re-install many time but it doesn't work, please help me. Thank you so much.***

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the env variable `OPENMC_CROSS_SECTIONS` on your operational system via terminal.

It worked for me on linux, however, I don't have experience with MACos.